# Give list of links tab like behaviour

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list of 4 links that I would like to give tab like behaviour to.

When one link is clicked I would like to turn it into text only. Then when a different link is clicked it should turn back into a clickable link. This would prevent someone clicking it twice, and show them which link is active.

Code looks like this:

```
<a href="">Link One</a>
<a href="">Link Two</a>
<a href="">Link Three</a>
<a href="">Link Four</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just give it a class when it is clicked, e.g.

```
$('a').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('active')) return; // this would stop any of the code below executing
  $('a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Then just give the active class a style which makes it look like text

Comment: (then just add all the other code that switches tabs, etc following in that click event function)

Comment: That's a really elegant solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to have 2 elements for each link. One with the anchor tags and the other without them in plaintext.

You could then hide the one with anchor tags when u click it and then show the plaintext for that link.

(will put up the code for this soon)